# Checking the checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://gyazo.com/2f4603d99ab60b2302f51bedf1ac600c.png?1367064154

Now I have the following code:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]#vibrat_vse_tovari_check_2').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari').addClass("active_cart_but_bolsh");
        $(".dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(".dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari").prop('disabled', true);
        $('.dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari').removeClass('active_cart_but_bolsh');
    }
});
```

The problem is that the removal of any checkbox makes the button inactive and necessary, what button was active until the last shot of any checkbox.

Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check *how many* checkboxes are checked before you can enable/disable it. What you have reacts only if any of the checkboxes changes.

You can check it with `length` like this:

`if($('input[type=checkbox]#vibrat_vse_tovari_check_2:checked').length >= x)`

Example here - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uhy9G/)

Also, ids should be unique. Use class instead.

Answer (score 0):

in your else clause, you need to check ALL the checkboxes in the group to see if any of them are checked. You're only checking  the one that was changed.

Also, in  html,the id attribute should be unique so your `#vibrat_vse_tovari_check_2'` in the  selector is either wrong, or if you've given all your checkboxes that same ID, then the html is wrong.